# Quiero hacer un filtro de búsqueda en tiempo real por el año de la fecha de la consulta en angular

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, filtro

Quiero hacer un filtro de búsqueda en tiempo real por el año de la fecha de la consulta en angular, tengo un tabla con el historial de la mascota seleccionada, y un buscador lo que quiero que al introducir el año me de las consultas que se han hecho en ese año en tiempo real.

Les muestro el ts.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HistorialService } from 'src/app/Servicios/historial/historial.service';
import { MascotasService } from 'src/app/Servicios/mascotas/mascotas.service';
import { Historial } from 'src/app/modelos/historial/historial.models';
import { Mascota } from 'src/app/modelos/mascota/mascota.models';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-historial-mascota',
 templateUrl: './historial-mascota.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./historial-mascota.component.scss']
 })
 export class HistorialMascotaComponent implements OnInit{
 mascotaIdentificador: string = '';
 mascota!: Mascota ;
 loading: boolean = true;
 currentPage = 1;
 historial: Historial[]= [];
 filterText = '';



constructor(
 private _mascotasService: MascotasService,
 private route: ActivatedRoute,
 private _historialService: HistorialService
 ) {}


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.mascotaIdentificador = String(
  this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));

  this._mascotasService
    .getMascotaID(this.mascotaIdentificador)
    .subscribe((mascota: Mascota) => {
      console.log(mascota);
      this.mascota = mascota;
    
      console.log(this.mascota.chip);
    });

    this._historialService.getHistorialID(this.mascotaIdentificador).subscribe(
      (data:Historial[] )=> {
        console.log(data);
      
        this.historial=data;
      },
      error => console.error(error)
      ); 


       console.log(this.historial)

     }


  }
```

Y este es el componente html donde se muestran los datos, el buscador lo tengo implementado, lo único que falta es que busque en tiempo real por el año, que es lo que no tengo ni idea.

```html
<div class="container w-100 mx-auto pt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12  w-100 d-flex gap-5">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-9 ">
            <div class="card text-center">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h2>Datos de la mascota </h2>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 card-body d-flex mx-auto cajaDatos justify-content-center">
                <div class="parrafo1 col-12 col-md-6 text-start">
                  <p class="fs-5 py-1 px-1">Raza: {{mascota.raza}}</p>
                  <p class="fs-5 py-1 px-1">Sexo: {{mascota.sexo}}</p>
                  <p class="fs-5 py-1 px-1">Chip: {{mascota.chip == 0 ? 'No tiene chip' : 'Si tiene chip'}}
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="parrafo2 col-12 col-md-6 text-start">
                  <p class="fs-5 py-1 px-1">Fecha de nacimiento: {{mascota.fecha_nacimiento}}</p>
                  <p class="fs-5 py-1 px-1">Identificador: {{mascota.identificador}}</p>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="card-footer text-end">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-warning" type="button" routerLink="/inicio/editar/{{mascota.identificador}}">
                                    Editar datos de la mascota
                                </button>

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-3 imagen text-end">
            <img src="../../../../../../assets/img/perro.png" class="w-100">
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row col-12">
          <div class="col-12 py-4 contenedorBuscador">
            <form action="" class="search-bar">
              <input type="search" name="search" required>
              <button class="search-btn" type="submit">
                                <span>Buscar</span>
                            </button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12">

            <div class="col-12 card">
              <div class="card-header text-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" routerLink="/inicio/crear-historial">Agregar consulta</button>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body table-responsive">
                <ng-container *ngIf="historial.length > 0; else noDataMessage">
                  <table class="table table-stripped py-4 table-hover text-center">
                    <thead class="text-truncate">
                      <th class="px-3">ID</th>
                      <th class="px-3">Nombre</th>
                      <th class="px-3">Identificador</th>
                      <th class="px-3">Raza</th>
                      <th class="px-3">Sexo</th>
                      <th class="px-3">Fecha de nacimiento</th>
                      <th class="px-3">Hora de la consulta</th>
                      <th class="px-3">Descripción de la consulta</th>
                      <th class="px-3">Fecha de la consulta</th>
                      <th class="px-3">Chip</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <tr *ngFor="let historial of historial  | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: currentPage } ">
                          <td>{{historial.id_historial}}</td>
                          <td>{{historial.nombre}}</td>
                          <td>{{historial.identificador}}</td>
                          <td>{{historial.raza}}</td>
                          <td>{{mascota.sexo}}</td>
                          <td>{{historial.fecha_nacimiento}}</td>
                          <td>{{historial.hora}}</td>
                          <td>{{historial.descripcion}}</td>
                          <td>{{historial.fecha}}</td>
                          <td>{{mascota.chip}}</td>


                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-template #noDataMessage>
                  <p class="text-center">No hay datos en la tabla historial disponibles en este momento.</p>
                </ng-template>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- aqui va la tabla -->
          <div class="text-center">

            <pagination-controls previousLabel="Anterior" nextLabel="Siguiente" (pageChange)="currentPage = $event"></pagination-controls>
          </div>

          <div class="text-end">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" routerLink="/inicio/panel">Volver al panel de gestión</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aqui les muestro la pagina donde quiero que el buscador funcione
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La forma más fácil que se me ocurre es crear un servicio donde envies la fecha como parámetro, puede ser en el body, y a partir de eso que te traiga lo que deseas. Por otro lado, sería una excelente idea separar todo el código que tienes, ya que muestras datos de la mascota, tienes un buscador y luego la tabla más abajo. Podrías tener componente de detalles, otro de buscar y luego  la tabla.

Comment: Si pero la cosa que no se como unirlos, el buscador no he visto las maneras de hacerlo, pero no las entiendo

Comment: Crea dos variables. Historial e Historial_stock por ejemplo. Historial será lo que muestres en el HTML. Cada vez que se realice una búsqueda, debes realizar un filter sobre Historial_stock e igualarlo a Historial para que se muestre en pantalla los datos filtrados. Si el input no tiene ningun valor, entonces igualas historial a historial_stock para que se muestren todos los registros del historial.

Historial > Muestra datos en pantalla
Historial_stock > Es tu almacén